# jQuery grep does not work right or maybe I do not understand it's usage

Tags: jquery, arrays, grep

I have an array of users and I am trying with a click to isolate one at a time.  From what I understand, grep is supposed to examine an array and create another array matching the values chosen.  The values come from an array of checkboxes in an accordion.  When I try this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.userWcb', function() {
        var chk = $(this);
        var ischecked = $(chk).is(':checked');
        var id = chk[0].id.substring(8);
        var len = UserArray.length;

        var pat = $.grep(UserArray, function (e) {
            var tst = e;
            return e.UserId = parseInt(id);
        });
        if (ischecked) {
            if (pat != null) {
                pat[0].PrintW = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (pat != null) {
                pat[0].PrintW = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

it doesn't work.  For example, when I have more than one item in the array it selects them all, no matter what the actual ID is.  But if I do this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.patientWristcb', function() {
        var chk = $(this);
        var ischecked = $(chk).is(':checked');
        var id = chk[0].id.substring(8);
        var len = UserArray.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var patid = UserArray[i].UserId;
            if (patid === parseInt(id)) {
                if (ischecked) {
                    UserArray[i].PrintW = true;
                }
                else {
                    UserArray[i].PrintW = false;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine.  Any ideas?